# Bokeh for presenting data on Italy map

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial, bokeh

I need to use Bokeh to plot datas on Italian map.

To explain, something similar with:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html

... but using italian provinces instead of Texas counties.

Can you help me pointing in the right direction?
Other tools suggested?

Thanks in advance, Gianluca

Comment: Do you have a source to obtain lat/lon coordinates for polygons that describe the boundaries of the provinces?

Comment: Not at the moment but I can try to find them if it's mandatory for the solution you're thinking about.

Comment: It's pretty much the only thing that has to be done. Bokeh ships with a handful of built-in data sets for demonstration purposes (like the counties of texas) but for other regions you'll need to supply the data. Then it's going to be similar or identical to the example, except with your new lat/lon data instead of texas counties.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can still help, but at http://www.istat.it/it/archivio/209722 (istat italian website)
you can find numerous free detailed and updated borders of Italian provinces and regions in .shp format.

Let me know if you manage to obtain your map and if yes, how, ty.

Comment: While this post snippet may solve the question, including an explanation along with some code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a plot with an Italian map.
I downloaded the borders of Italy from github ([region borders](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pasqualemauriello/italy/master/json/regioni.json) or [province borders](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pasqualemauriello/italy/master/json/province.json)).
Then I created a dataframe containing 3 columns: [Province (or region), x_bord, y_bord].
In the end I used it as a ColumnDataSource and create a Figure with patches.

Suggestion: if you want to improve your render, you can add a hover tool creating a new column with desired values (e.g. number of inhabitants). Moreover you can create new column containing rgb values (RGB(r,g,b)) if you want different colors for each province or region.

```
source= ColumnDataSource(dict(x=italy.x_bord,y=italy.y_bord,prov=italy.prov,val=italy.val,colors=italy.colors))
f = figure(...)
f.patches(xs='x',ys='y',source=source, fill_color='colors')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with shape files from ISTAT.

If you want you can use my library for geo analysis within ITALY in easier way ([here](https://github.com/stefanogelli92/geo_ita) you can find the github link).

You just need to download the whl, install (you can see the readme part) and use it.

Here an example:

Suppose you have a dataframe (df) like this

[image]

then you can run this code

```
from geo_ita.plot import plot_choropleth_map_provinciale_interactive
plot_choropleth_map_provinciale_interactive(df, province_tag='provincia', value_tag='valore')
```